# Query object EntitlementProcessMilestoneItem

Tags: entitlements

Is it possible to query object: EntitlementProcessMilestoneItem.
I understand it's the milestones in the entitlment, however when trying to query I get error:

> sObject type 'EntitlementProcessMilestoneItem' is not supported.

Any other way, to query the milestone setup in entitelment process?

Comment: Try [MilestoneType](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_milestonetype.htm) object.

Comment: Hi.this is milestone setup (e.g. Response Time). I need the milestones in entitlement process.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are finding the [CaseMilestone](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_casemilestone.htm).
Hope it can help.

Comment: No. It isn't. CaseMilstonce- is the milestone under the case. I'm looking for the milstone under the entitlement. When setup the entitlement via setup, you setup also the milestone in the process. I can query the entitlement by object SLAProcess, but I cannot get the milestone linked to it